# Lxml equivalent for BeautifulSoup find()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I recently switched from Beautifulsoup to lxml because lxml can work with broken HTML, which is my case. I wanted to know what is the equivalent or a programatic form of acomplishing Beautifulsoup find(). You see in BS I am able to find a tree node by searching like this:

```
bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
bs.find('span', {'class': 'some-class-name'})
```

lxml find() just searching the current level on the tree, what if I want to search in all the tree nodes ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`cssselect`](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html):

```
root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
root.cssselect('span.some-class-name')
```

or [`xpath`](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html):

```
root.xpath('.//span[@class="some-class-name"]')
```

Both `cssselect`, `xpath` methods return a list of matched element like `findAll/find_all` method in BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't want to bother learning the api for `lxml` or `xpath` expressions, then here's another option:

From: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

> Beautiful Soup supports the HTML parser included in Python’s standard library, but it also supports a number of third-party Python parsers. One is the lxml parser [...]

And to specify a specific parser to use:

```
BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml")
```